# python rpg syntax error on a ":"

Tags: python, pygame, syntax-error

im creating a **rpg game** and **i was defining the rooms content and position** but it pops tis error when executing the program.

```
  File "my.py", line 82
    "item"    :   ""
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**line 82 is the first room**, but i guess it will apply to all of them.
please i really don't know why the **":"** is wrong.

```
rooms = {
        1 : {   "name"    :   "Your room"
                "item"    :   ""
                "down"    :   2
                "right"   :   3},

        2 : {   "name"    :   "Bathroom"
                "item"    :   "Useless soap"
                "up"      :   1
                "right"   :   4},
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You need commas after every item.

```
rooms = {
        1 : {   "name"    :   "Your room",
                "item"    :   "",
                "down"    :   2,
                "right"   :   3},
```